Authentication error using Office365-REST-Python-Client connecting to Sharepoint
I had code to download a file, filter it, and upload it to Sharepoint. It worked perfectly for two days, now I am getting an authentication error trying to connect. I am using username and password for my credentials, I couldn't authenticate using the APIs...
I do not have 2fa set up on my account.
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date

# Your CSV file link
url = "https://csvlink"

# Load the data and parse 'PurchaseDate(UTC)' as a datetime object
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['PurchaseDate(UTC)'])

# Convert 'PurchaseDate(UTC)' from DateTime to Date
df['PurchaseDate(UTC)'] = df['PurchaseDate(UTC)'].dt.date

# Find the minimum date in the 'PurchaseDate(UTC)' column and add one day
min_date = df['PurchaseDate(UTC)'].min() + timedelta(days=1)

# Filter the DataFrame to keep only rows with the minimum date
filtered_df = df[df['PurchaseDate(UTC)'] == min_date]

# Convert the filtered DataFrame to a CSV format in memory
csv_buffer = BytesIO()
filtered_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
csv_buffer.seek(0)  # Move to the start of the BytesIO buffer

# SharePoint site URL and folder location
site_url = "https://mybusiness.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName"
relative_folder_url = "/sites/SiteName/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3"

# File name for SharePoint
file_name = f"{min_date.year}.{min_date.month:02d}.{min_date.day:02d}" + '_orders.csv'

# User credentials (in production, these should be securely stored)
username = "email"
password = "password"

# Authenticate using user credentials
auth_ctx = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
if not auth_ctx.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    print("Authentication failed: ", auth_ctx.get_last_error())
    exit()

ctx = ClientContext(site_url, auth_ctx)

# Ensure the folder exists and upload the file
target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_folder_url).get().execute_query()

# Upload the file to SharePoint
target_folder.upload_file(file_name, csv_buffer.getvalue())  # Upload the in-memory CSV file
ctx.execute_query()```

I get a long string of errors but this is the last line: 

ValueError: Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf

Any help is appreciated, I am very new to python. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!


I have tried enabling and disabling 2FA on my account, I have tried using Azure active directory API to authenticate using Client ID and Secret, I have tried different plugins, I have tried authenticating different ways using the same plugin. 

